# L'Hospital's Rule and Transfer Function

Tags: calculus

In an Electrical Engineering Textbook I am given this function:

$$ H_C(j\omega) = \frac{10^6j\omega}{10^{10} + -\omega^2 + 10^5j\omega} $$

where $j = \sqrt{-1}, \omega = 2\pi f, f=frequency (Hz) $

The text book goes on to say 'the high frequency asymptote is

$$ H(j\omega) = \frac{10^6}{j\omega} $$'

If I take the limit as $\omega -> \infty$, then isn't the fraction in the form $ \frac{\infty}{\infty}$. If not, why not? When I apply L'Hospitals Rule here, I do not get the same answer for the high-frequency asymptote, I get $$ \frac{10^6j}{-2\omega + 10^5j} $$, so in the limit, the function goes to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there. The only thing left to note is that $|10^5j| < \omega$ for large enough $\omega$. Thus, your fraction becomes $\frac{10^6j}{-2\omega}$, which is the suggested answer apart from a factor of $\frac12$, but I believe that this is just a typo in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from an abuse of notation. The 'high frequency asymptote', denoted by $\omega \to \infty$, shouldn't be understood as a limit. Actually, your book aims to study the behaviour of the transfer function $H(j\omega)$ for high values of $\omega$, i.e. when $\omega \gg 1$, which is not the same as its value at infinity. You are looking for an approximated *function* and not for a limit *value*. In consquence, you cannot use L'Hospital's rule.

In the end, you only need to factorize the expression, as follows :
$$
H(j\omega) = \frac{10^6j\omega}{(j\omega)^2} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{10^5}{j\omega} + \frac{10^{10}}{(j\omega)^2}} \approx \frac{10^6}{j\omega},
$$
and to argue that the last two terms of the denominator are negligible when $\omega \gg 1$.